# CSS keyframe animation div not visible

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to make a very simple animation with CSS, but I cant see the div that the animation controls.
If I use inspect element I can see that the div is there, and is moving properly, but it is completely invisible, even in any browser I test it in.
Here's the  [example](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_animation_count2) my code is based off of.

My code:

```
<html>
 <head>
     <style>
         div {
             height: 100 px;
             width: 100px;
             background-color: red;
             position: relative;
             animation-name: example;
             animation-duration: 4s;
             animation-iteration-count: infinite;
         }
         @keyframes example {
             0%    {background-color:red; left: 0px; top: 0px;}
             50%   {background-color:green; left: 100px; top: 0px;}
             100%  {background-color:blue; left: 50px; top: 50px}
         }
     </style>
 </head>
 <body style="width: 100% height: 100%;">
     <div></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your div selector, there is a space between the value and unit.

```
height: 100 px;
```